# Facing issue in Load Runner

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I am new to load runner tool.I have to perform load testing for payment gateways. When I record the script using HP Load Runner the script is recorded successfully. When i replay the same script to check whether script is passed or not. Then, script does not show any error.So,i started giving load on the same script then for the payment the entry which i am getting in transaction list in "Awaiting" and when i do manually payment the entry i get is "Completed".So, according to the "Awaiting" status payment is not done successfully.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the loadrunner script you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to load runner tool.

Have you had training in the tool?

Have you been provided a mentor for a period of time until you are proficient with the tool?

Has your management refused you access to either of the two previous items?

Comment: No I learned the tool from tutorials and no management has not refused. @James Pulley

Comment: This is a path which does not have a track record of success.   Referring to the tutorials, consider the manual model for dynamic data identification involving multiple recordings and comparison

Comment: So, @James Pulley what i can do to resolve the problem?

Comment: You follow the manual methods as outlined in training, the tutorials, the manuals for recording multiple times to identify the dynamic data that likely needs to be addressed as part of the payment gateway correct operation.  Also, you may want to consider service virtualization of the payment gateway as the gateway provider has likely sized it for functional work in QA and the client is likely paying for every incident of use.